# Removing occurences of #ifdef/#endif from a file with perl

Tags: xcode, perl, xcode4, xcode4.5

I have a code file that has some #ifdefs I would like removed in the header file after building a library. My first thought was to do this as a perl script that XCode can run. While I can certainly open the header file and read all content of it into a string in perl, I'm curious as to the best way to do the following

1. Find any occurrence of #ifdef EXAMPLE
2. Remove it and anything in between the following #endif

So the example is:

```
int i;
NSString *someString;
#ifdef EXAMPLE
NSString *exampleString;
#endif
bool done;
```

and the output would be:

```
int i;
NSString *someString;
bool done;
```

Options I'm considering:

- finding index of every #ifdef EXAMPLE and removing it via substring with the next found #endif
- Write a regex that can somehow remove these occurences.

Considering I haven't written Perl before (Objective-C is my primary language) I was curious if any XCode or Perl developers had any suggestions on what the best approach would be

Comment: Why do you want to remove the ifdefs?

Comment: Why not just use the C preprocessor?

Comment: @MichaelCarman Why not show him how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to strip out ifdefs, and you can probably use a C pre-processor to do this, but here's how you'd do it in Perl because it means I get to play with the flip-flop operator.

First thing is to craft a sufficient regex to match the ifdefs.  IIRC they can be indented and there can be indentation between the `#` and the word.

```
#ifdef
#    ifdef
    #ifdef
```

Not sure if that last one is valid, but I'm going with it anyway.

```
my $ifdef_re = qr{^\s*#\s*ifdef\b};
my $endif_re = qr{^\s*#\s*endif\b};
```

If it was just removing text between `#ifdef` and `#endif`, Perl has the little used [flip flop scalar `..` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $ifdef_re = qr{^\s*#\s*ifdef\b};
my $endif_re = qr{^\s*#\s*endif\b};

while(<DATA>) {
    my $in_ifdef = /$ifdef_re/ .. /$endif_re/;

    print if !$in_ifdef;
}

__DATA__
int i;
NSString *someString;
#ifdef EXAMPLE
NSString *exampleString;
#endif
bool done;
```

But since we need to worry about nested ifdefs, its insufficient.  A depth counter takes care of that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $ifdef_re = qr{^\s*#\s*ifdef\b};
my $endif_re = qr{^\s*#\s*endif\b};

my $ifdef_count = 0;
while(<DATA>) {
    $ifdef_count++ if /$ifdef_re/;

    print if $ifdef_count <= 0;

    $ifdef_count-- if /$endif_re/;
}

__DATA__
int i;
NSString *someString;
#ifdef EXAMPLE
NSString *exampleString;
#    ifdef FOO
this should not appear
#    endif
nor should this
#endif
bool done;
```

Comment: I'm not clear why you are coding for nested `#ifdef` statements, especially without also catering for `#else` statements. It's not part of the question.

Comment: @Borodin Expert advice is a collaborative process. Its not just about answering the question, but addressing their problem.  A problem they may not have the knowledge and experience to fully think through or express, or just didn't have the time to come up with a complete example.  Its my part to fill in those gaps.  Nested `#ifdefs` are going to come up in any interesting code base.  To not address it would be lying by omission.  (`#else` statements don't increase nesting so they can be safely ignored)

Answer (score 1):

I love regexes, but for this problem I wouldn't use a regex, I'd just read line by line, keeping track of whether I was inside a ifdef:

```
my $nesting = 0;
while (<STDIN>)
   {
   $nesting += 1 if /^#ifdef/;
   print $_ unless $nesting;
   $nesting -= 1 if /^#endif/;
   }
```

If you really want to use a regex, and have read the whole file into the variable `$source`, I think this will work, if you don't need to worry about nesting:

```
$source =~ s/^#ifdef.*?^#endif.*?$//gms;
```

The `^` characters anchor those parts of the expression to the beginning of a line. The `$` makes the last part of the match only happen at the end of a line.

The `.*?` behaves almost like `.*`, which matches zero or more characters, except that it does minimal matching. So instead of matching all the way to the last `#endif`, it matches to the first one.

The `/gms` at the end makes it:

1. Substitute every occurrence, not just one (that's the g)
2. Make ^ and $ match at line boundaries, not just string boundaries (the m)
3. Make . match newlines (the s)

You might want to follow every `#ifdef` and `#endif` with `\s`, to only match if there is whitespace following that string.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just do this with [`unifdef`](http://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/). XCode installs this by default:

```
-U will remove #ifdef and matching #else/#endif as if <constant> is undefined.
-D will remove #ifdef and matching #else/#endif as if <constant> is defined.
```

Here's an example:

```
$ cat test.h
#ifdef TEST

#ifdef DEBUG
# define AWESOME_DEBUG_LEVEL 1
#else
# define AWESOME_DEBUG_LEVEL 0
#endif

#endif

$ unifdef -U DEBUG test.h
#ifdef TEST

# define AWESOME_DEBUG_LEVEL 0

#endif

$ unifdef -U DEBUG -D TEST test.h

# define AWESOME_DEBUG_LEVEL 0
```